# Directx get VRAM used by game

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to get the total amount of VRAM my game is currently using. I want to display this in my debug information.

When I was using the `Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer` I got an idea.
I figured that I could get the amount of VRAM used by adding the size of each of the graphic objects as seen in the `Graphics Object Table`.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to get each of those objects. Is there a simple way to get these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found an easier way to do this:

```
#include <dxgi1_4.h>
```

...

```
IDXGIFactory4* pFactory;
CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory4), (void**)&pFactory);

IDXGIAdapter3* adapter;
pFactory->EnumAdapters(0, reinterpret_cast<IDXGIAdapter**>(&adapter));

DXGI_QUERY_VIDEO_MEMORY_INFO videoMemoryInfo;
adapter->QueryVideoMemoryInfo(0, DXGI_MEMORY_SEGMENT_GROUP_LOCAL, &videoMemoryInfo);

size_t usedVRAM = videoMemoryInfo.CurrentUsage / 1024 / 1024;
```

This gets the currently used VRAM from the default (ID 0) adapter and converts it to megabytes.

***Note: This does require the use of the windows 10 SDK***